# Where does Cargo get my name and email from when creating a project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Working through Rust's [Getting Started](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/getting-started.html) page on macOS, I ran the following command for Cargo to generate a project:

```
cargo new hello_world --bin
```

When I inspected the `Cargo.toml` file, it contained my real name as well as my email address.

From where is Cargo getting my name and email? How can I configure the name and email address Cargo uses?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Cargo uses your git configuration, among other environment variables](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/0.27.0/src/cargo/ops/cargo_new.rs#L587-L633).

To override it, you should be able to set the `CARGO_EMAIL` and `CARGO_NAME` environment variables when running cargo. E.g:

```
CARGO_NAME=not-ross cargo new --bin project_name
```

For example:

```
simon /c/rust
$ CARGO_NAME=Not-Simon CARGO_EMAIL=not_simon@not_simon.com cargo new --bin override-author
     Created binary (application) `override-author` project

simon /c/rust
$ cd !$

simon /c/rust/override-author (master)
$ cat Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "override-author"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Not-Simon <not_simon@not_simon.com>"]

[dependencies]
```

Using `CARGO_NAME` and `CARGO_EMAIL` lets `cargo` figure out the author name and email at a higher "scope". Looking at the code in more detail, it will check git first but you can override it with the `--vcs` flag which will still use `CARGO_NAME` and `CARGO_EMAIL` if provided.